# Create a nested HASH from a API Call doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby

I am new here and i hope that I'm doing everything right.
I also searched the Forum and with Googel, but I didn't find the answer. (Or I did not notice that the solution lies before my eyes. Then I'm sorry >.< .)

i have a problem and i dont exactly know what i am doing wrong at the moment. 
I make a API request and get a big JSON back. It looks somehow like that:

```
"apps": [
        {
            "title": "XX",
             ... many more data
},
{
            "title": "XX",
            ... many more data
},
{
            "title": "XX",
            ... many more data
} 
    ... and so on
]
```

After that i want to create a hash with the data i need, for example it should look like:

```
{
 "APP_0" => {"Title"=>"Name1", "ID"=>"1234", "OS"=>"os"}
 "APP_1" => {"Title"=>"Name2", "ID"=>"5678", "OS"=>"os"}
}
```

but the values in the hash that i create with my code looks like:

```
"APP_1", {"Title"=>"Name2", "ID"=>"5678", "OS"=>"os"}
```

dont now if this is a valid hash? And after that i want to iterate through the Hash and just output the ID. But I get an error (TypeError). What am i doing wrong?

```
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'httparty'

response = HTTParty.get('https://xxx/api/2/app', {
  headers: {"X-Toke" => "xyz"},
})
all_apps_parse = JSON.parse(response.body)

all_apps = Hash.new
all_apps_parse["apps"].each_with_index do |app, i|
  all_apps["APP_#{i}"] = {'Title' => app["title"],
                         'ID' => app["id"],
                         'OS' => app["platform"]}
end

all_apps.each_with_index do |app, i|
  app_id = app["App_#{i}"]["id"]
  p app_id
end
```

I hope someone can understand the problem and can help me :-). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please paste the error and stack trace in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data looks something like this:

```
all_apps_parse = { "apps" => [
                   {
                     "title" => "Name1",
                     "id" => 1234,
                     "platform" => "os"
                   },
                   {
                     "title" => "Name2",
                     "id" => 5678,
                     "platform" => "os"
                   },
                   {
                     "title" => "Name3",
                     "id" => 1111,
                     "platform" => "windows"
                   }]
                 }
```

and with a little idea of what you want to achieve, here is my solution:

```
all_apps = Hash.new
all_apps_parse["apps"].each_with_index do |app, i|
  all_apps["APP_#{i}"] = { 'Title' => app["title"],
                           'ID' => app["id"],
                           'OS' => app["platform"] }
end

all_apps
 => {"APP_0"=>{"Title"=>"Name1", "ID"=>1234, "OS"=>"os"}, "APP_1"=>{"Title"=>"Name2", "ID"=>5678, "OS"=>"os"}, "APP_2"=>{"Title"=>"Name3", "ID"=>1111, "OS"=>"windows"}}

all_apps.each do |key, value|
  puts key              # => e.g. "APP_0"
  puts value['ID']      # => e.g. 1234
end

# Prints 
APP_0
1234
APP_1
5678
APP_2
1111
```

Comment: Thank you that works. A simple solution and i did not get up to this by myself >.<. I am a little bit confused because my output looked like described (, and not =>). But magically, it looks right now >.<. Thanks a lot.